# parsing array from ajax into php

Tags: php, ajax, post

i want to pass array which is generated by javascript..just say i have an array named vals2=('john','peter') and i want to pass this array to my php page(insert_paket_f.php).

**this is my ajax code :**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_paket_f.php",
        data: { data : vals2 },
        cache: false,
        //vals=('john','peter','andrea');
        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

**insert_paket_f.php**

```
$data1 = $_POST['data'];                
$data1 = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
print_r($data1);
```

when i run my browser, its show empty array, and just looks like this **Array ( [0] => )**

how can i fix this?

thanks..

Comment: Try: $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "insert_paket_f.php", data: {'data[]' : {a:'1', b : '2'}}, ........

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use `join` to send the javascript array as an string.

**Javascript**

```
var vals2 = ['john','peter'];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert_paket_f.php",
    data: { data : vals2.join(',') },
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$data1 = $_POST['data'];                
$data1 = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
print_r($data1);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "my array already contain ',' (coma)"? Please explain so that i can explain it furthur.

Comment: If you mean `','` in the `join` function, i do it to convert the array to an string which is sent to the php and php converts it back to an array using `explode`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$data1 = json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Data Feild try to use variables

as
    echo data: data[]=john&data[]=peter&data[]=andrea

**Code:-**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert_paket_f.php",
    data: "data[]=john&data[]=peter&data[]=andrea",
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

Is It working?

Comment: the array is generated by javascript and populated from dynamic dropdown..so i cant do your code..btw thanks for trying to help me :D